Is it common or legal for a employer to lie about why an employee was terminated?
Let's suppose that an employee was terminated without any prior warning or reviews suggesting poor performance.
In the termination meeting, the manage states that the reason is company restructuring and the "position" has been terminated.
The manager did not state anything regarding the employee or their performance as the reason.
Is it common or legal for the above scenario when in the fact the reason were the employee's performance? In other words, is it common or legal for employers to lie to the employee of why they were terminated?

It can certainly be illegal under some situations. You'll have to tell us your jurisdiction for a proper answer.

edited @GregoryCurrie

Workplace law is dependant on state in the USA.

Most states in the US are "at-will" states meaning that (with a few exceptions) an employer can terminate you for any reason or no reason at all. They can say whatever they want or nothing at all.

What is your end goal? It doesn’t sound a job exists for this individual, regardless, if they were fired for their performance or because of corporate restructuring. Which to be honest could both be true. In many states within the US, a company often isn’t actually required to give a reason for laying off an employee.

It's legal for them to say whatever they want, and most companies won't because it tends to lead to expensive and public lawsuits that damage brands.

It is no longer common in the US for larger companies to officially say anything more than confirming the dates worked. Of course if managers at old and new community many know each other, back-channel unofficial communication may occur, and there's no control over that either way.

In the US, there are two different types of termination. When someone is "fired", generally that means that they were fired for cause. In that case, many states refuse unemployment payments to the fired individual.
The other type of termination is "lay off" which means that the position has been eliminated. When this happens, the states may pay unemployment to the person.
If the company is terminating someone for cause, but states that the position is eliminated, that is a kindness to the person allowing them to get unemployment compensation.


In other words, is it common or legal for employers to lie to the employee of why they were terminated?

It is common to say as little as possible to the terminated employee to avoid legal or interpersonal complications. It is legal to say something gentler to the employee than, "you're not good enough to keep around." (Lying to regulators might be illegal).

For:

USA
At Will State
Non-Union Position

The simple fact is the less the employee says the better it is for them.
From an employer's perspective it is next to impossible to successfully challenge State unemployment insurance claims. The more said, the more likely the employer will get sued for something.
For those that don't understand the unemployment claims reference. The employer's SUI (State Unemployment Insurance) tax rate is usually tied to the amount of claims they've had. However, rarely is terminated employee denied unemployment, even in cases of egregious actions. So many, if not most, employers don't bother fighting unemployment claims.
This along with sue at the drop of hat thinking, creates the say as little as possible. "It's not you, its me", restructuring - is a safe bet to fire somebody. Who can say that next week you don't restructure again?
Is it lie? That is up to you to say what you think.

In Australia, if you want to fire someone for poor performance, there is a mandated process that need to be followed.
If you wish to make a role redundant, there is a different process that must be followed.
Different processes give employees different rights, and place different burdens on an employer.
If an employer makes misrepresentations about a workers rights, that could be unlawful.
For example, if an employee was underperforming, and the employer decided to fire the employee but pretend it was due to a role being made redundant, there may be a case against the employer because they have not given the employee a written warning, and a personal improvement plan. Because they have pretended the role is redundant, they have mislead the ex-employee about their rights.

Generally this is only Illegal if the position hasn't been terminated
This is not legal advise, I am not a Lawyer - but the general rule is that if a Company makes a role redundant, then yes - they can terminate you. Redundancy laws vary wildly by country as to what processes have to be followed etc. And in the US with a right to work, this is not really relevant.
However, if they re-hire someone else, for the same or similar position (even if the job title is different - if it can be proved that it is essentially the same position) - then that is usually illegal.

This is a very high bar to proven for being illegal. There almost always has to be violation of a protection that can be proved.
